# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'drop_duplicates'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im getting AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'drop_duplicates' when running this code , any ideas how to solve this ?

**first module interface.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 720, height = 360, bg = 'lightsteelblue')
canvas1.pack()

def getExcel ():
    global df
    
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df =  pd.read_excel(import_file_path, sheet_name=None)
    return df
    
browseButton_Excel = tk.Button(text='Import Excel File', command=getExcel, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(360, 180, window=browseButton_Excel)

root.mainloop()
```

**second module**

```
import interface

bgxp = []
data = interface.df
#data = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Users\us\Desktop\grauation project\Deliveries 12-3-2017.xlsx') 
#data = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('Todays sheet.xlsx', sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
#data1 drops all dublicates from sheet 
data1 = data.drop_duplicates(subset=["Ref/Lic Nr"], keep="first")
#data = interface.df 
cr = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns= ['Carrier'])
rf = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns= ['Ref/Lic Nr'])

#Locks data from column 
amtg = data1.loc[data1.Carrier=='AMTG', 'Ref/Lic Nr']
#  without index
amtg1=(amtg.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

Comment: Is the first module named interface.py?

Comment: yes, let me update the question

Comment: Let's debug. Add `print(df)` on two places: the interface module as the last line and the second module after you assing data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

> Returns DataFrame **or dict of DataFrames**

When you specify `sheet_name=None` it reads in **all** sheets so the the returned object is a dict of DataFrames of the form: `{sheet_name: pd.DataFrame}`

---

If all the sheets share similar fields a good solution is to turn that into a MultiIndexed DataFrame, where the sheet_names are added as the first 0th-index level.

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(import_file_path, sheet_name=None))
```

Otherwise you'll need to iterate over the dict.

Comment: Thank you mate for great explanation , im new to whole python coding and this answer was exactly what i need)

Comment: @YaroslawKorol, Welcome to SO.. If you feel that above answer helped you, you could [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).