# Trying to fill NA inpalce of null entity but getting error

Tags: python, pandas

```
    filename = input("Input the Filename: ")
    dfs = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None)
    dfs.fillna('NA', inplace = True) #placing
    
    print (dfs.keys()) #print the name of sheets
```

> ERROR: 
>  AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fillna'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'drop\_duplicates'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63208490/attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-attribute-drop-duplicates)

Comment: Please refer to the documentation of the function you are using. The answer is in there. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dfs` is a dictionary. So it won't work. Instead of

```
dfs.fillna('NA', inplace = True)
```

iterate over the values instead:

```
for df in dfs.values():
    df.fillna('NA', inplace = True)
```

Comment: Yes it can solve the problem of df and dfs but still object is not subcriptable error appears.